# Applying VGG16 for 10 images but get the value error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

> The proposed method can automatically detect the features of medical images under the condition determined by the algorithms, and achieve the correct and fast recognition results.

I was trying to run the image classification with using CNN method but then I got the error message below

```
  File "<ipython-input-2-4e7ea6cc5087>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/MDIC/Desktop/VGG for 10 Images.py', wdir='C:/Users/MDIC/Desktop')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/MDIC/Desktop/VGG for 10 Images.py", line 224, in <module>
    sp = plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, i + 1)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1084, in subplot
    a = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1367, in add_subplot
    a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 60, in __init__
    ).format(maxn=rows*cols, num=num))

ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 25, not 26
```

This is my Python code

```
# Importing libraries
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import os

# Preparing dataset
# Setting names of the directies for ten sets
base_dir = 'data'
seta ='Man1'
setb ='Man2'
setc ='Man3'
setd ='Man4'
sete ='Man5'
setf ='Man6'
setg ='Man7'
seth ='Man8'
seti ='Man9'
setj ='Man10'

# Each of the sets has three sub directories train, validation and test
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'validation')
test_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'test')

def prepare_data(base_dir, seta, setb, setc, setd, sete, setf, setg, seth, seti, setj):
# Take the directory names for the base directory and both the sets 
# Returns the paths for train, validation for each of the sets
    seta_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, seta)
    setb_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, setb)
    setc_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, setc)
    setd_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, setd)
    sete_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, sete)
    setf_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, setf)
    setg_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, setg)
    seth_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, seth)
    seti_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, seti)
    setj_train_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, setj)
    
    seta_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, seta)
    setb_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, setb)
    setc_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, setc)
    setd_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, setd)
    sete_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, sete)
    setf_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, setf)
    setg_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, setg)
    seth_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, seth)
    seti_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, seti)
    setj_valid_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, setj)

    seta_train_fnames = os.listdir(seta_train_dir)
    setb_train_fnames = os.listdir(setb_train_dir)
    setc_train_fnames = os.listdir(setc_train_dir)
    setd_train_fnames = os.listdir(setd_train_dir)
    sete_train_fnames = os.listdir(sete_train_dir)
    setf_train_fnames = os.listdir(setf_train_dir)
    setg_train_fnames = os.listdir(setg_train_dir)
    seth_train_fnames = os.listdir(seth_train_dir)
    seti_train_fnames = os.listdir(seti_train_dir)
    setj_train_fnames = os.listdir(setj_train_dir)
 
    return seta_train_dir, setb_train_dir, setc_train_dir, setd_train_dir, sete_train_dir, setf_train_dir, setg_train_dir, seth_train_dir, seti_train_dir, setj_train_dir, seta_valid_dir, setb_valid_dir, setc_valid_dir, setd_valid_dir, sete_valid_dir, setf_valid_dir, setg_valid_dir, seth_valid_dir, seti_valid_dir, setj_valid_dir, seta_train_fnames, setb_train_fnames, setc_train_fnames, setd_train_fnames, sete_train_fnames, setf_train_fnames, setg_train_fnames, seth_train_fnames, seti_train_fnames, setj_train_fnames            
           
seta_train_dir, setb_train_dir, setc_train_dir, setd_train_dir, sete_train_dir, setf_train_dir, setg_train_dir, seth_train_dir, seti_train_dir, setj_train_dir, seta_valid_dir, setb_valid_dir, setc_valid_dir, setd_valid_dir, sete_valid_dir, setf_valid_dir, setg_valid_dir, seth_valid_dir, seti_valid_dir, setj_valid_dir, seta_train_fnames, setb_train_fnames, setc_train_fnames, setd_train_fnames, sete_train_fnames, setf_train_fnames, setg_train_fnames, seth_train_fnames, seti_train_fnames, setj_train_fnames = prepare_data(base_dir, seta, setb, setc, setd, sete, setf, setg, seth, seti, setj)

seta_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, seta)
setb_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, setb)
setc_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, setc)
setd_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, setd)
sete_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, sete)
setf_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, setf)
setg_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, setg)
seth_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, seth)
seti_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, seti)
setj_test_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, setj)

test_fnames_seta = os.listdir(seta_test_dir)
test_fnames_setb = os.listdir(setb_test_dir)
test_fnames_setc = os.listdir(setc_test_dir)
test_fnames_setd = os.listdir(setd_test_dir)
test_fnames_sete = os.listdir(sete_test_dir)
test_fnames_setf = os.listdir(setf_test_dir)
test_fnames_setg = os.listdir(setg_test_dir)
test_fnames_seth = os.listdir(seth_test_dir)
test_fnames_seti = os.listdir(seti_test_dir)
test_fnames_setj = os.listdir(setj_test_dir)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator( 
          height_shift_range = 0.2,
          width_shift_range = 0.2,
          rotation_range = 40,
          shear_range = 0.2,
          zoom_range = 0.2,
          horizontal_flip = True,
          fill_mode = 'nearest')

img_path = os.path.join(seta_train_dir, seta_train_fnames[3])
img = load_img(img_path, target_size = (150, 150))
x = img_to_array(img)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)

i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size = 1):
    plt.figure(i)
    imgplot = plt.imshow(array_to_img(batch[0]))
    i += 1
    if i % 10 == 0:
        break
        
# Convolutional Neural Network model
# Import TensorFlow libraries
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

img_input = layers.Input(shape = (150, 150, 3))        

# 2D Convolution layer with 64 filters of dimension 3x3 and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu')(img_input)
# 2D max pooling layer
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)

# 2D Convolution layer with 128 filters of dimension 3x3 and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
# 2D Max pooling layer
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)

# 2D Convolution layer with 256 filters of dimension 3x3 and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
# 2D Max pooling layer
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)

# 2D Convolution layer with 512 filters of dimension 3x3 and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
# 2D Max pooling layer
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)

# 2D Convolution layer with 512 filters of dimension 3x3 and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu')(x)
# Flatten layer
x = layers.Flatten()(x)

# Fully connected layers and ReLU activation algorithm
x = layers.Dense(4096, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(4096, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(1000, activation = 'relu')(x)

# Dropout layers for optimisation
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)

# Fully connected layers and sigmoid activation algorithm
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10))
output = layers.Dense(10, activation = 'sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(img_input, output)

model.summary()

import tensorflow as tf

# Using binary_crossentropy as the loss function and
# Adam optimizer as the optimizing function when training
model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.0005),
              metrics = ['acc'])
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator                  

# All images will be rescaled by 1./255
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

# Flow training images in batches of 20 using train_datagen generator
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                  train_dir,
                  target_size = (150, 150),
                  batch_size = 20,
                  class_mode = 'binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                       validation_dir,
                       target_size = (150, 150),
                       batch_size = 20,
                       class_mode = 'binary')

# 4x4 grid
nrows = 5
ncols = 5

pic_index = 0

# Set up matpotlib fig and size it to fit 5x5 pics
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(nrows * 5, ncols * 5)

pic_index += 10
next_seta_pix = [os.path.join(seta_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in seta_train_fnames[pic_index-10:pic_index]]
next_setb_pix = [os.path.join(setb_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in setb_train_fnames[pic_index-10:pic_index]]
next_setc_pix = [os.path.join(setc_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in setc_train_fnames[pic_index-10:pic_index]]
next_setd_pix = [os.path.join(setd_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in setd_train_fnames[pic_index-10:pic_index]]
next_sete_pix = [os.path.join(sete_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in sete_train_fnames[pic_index-10:pic_index]]
next_setf_pix = [os.path.join(setf_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in setf_train_fnames[pic_index-10:pic_index]]
next_setg_pix = [os.path.join(setg_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in setg_train_fnames[pic_index-10:pic_index]]
next_seth_pix = [os.path.join(seth_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in seth_train_fnames[pic_index-10:pic_index]]
next_seti_pix = [os.path.join(seti_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in seti_train_fnames[pic_index-10:pic_index]]
next_setj_pix = [os.path.join(setj_train_dir, fname)
                 for fname in setj_train_fnames[pic_index-10:pic_index]]

for i, img_path in enumerate(next_seta_pix + next_setb_pix + next_setc_pix + next_setd_pix + next_sete_pix + next_setf_pix + next_setg_pix + next_seth_pix + next_seti_pix + next_setj_pix):
    # Set up subplot; subplot indices start at 1
    sp = plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, i + 1)
# Dont show axes
    sp.axis('Off')

    img = mpimg.imread(img_path)
    plt.imshow(img)
    
plt.show()

# Train the model
mymodel = model.fit_generator(
          train_generator,
          steps_per_epoch = 10,
          epochs = 80,
          validation_data = validation_generator,
          validation_steps = 7,
          verbose = 2)

import random
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img

successive_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers[1:]]
visualization_model = Model(img_input, successive_outputs)

a_img_files = [os.path.join(seta_train_dir, f) for f in seta_train_fnames]
b_img_files = [os.path.join(setb_train_dir, f) for f in setb_train_fnames]
c_img_files = [os.path.join(setc_train_dir, f) for f in setc_train_fnames]
d_img_files = [os.path.join(setd_train_dir, f) for f in setd_train_fnames]
e_img_files = [os.path.join(sete_train_dir, f) for f in sete_train_fnames]
f_img_files = [os.path.join(setf_train_dir, f) for f in setf_train_fnames]
g_img_files = [os.path.join(setg_train_dir, f) for f in setg_train_fnames]
h_img_files = [os.path.join(seth_train_dir, f) for f in seth_train_fnames]
i_img_files = [os.path.join(seti_train_dir, f) for f in seti_train_fnames]
j_img_files = [os.path.join(setj_train_dir, f) for f in setj_train_fnames]

img_path = random.choice(a_img_files + b_img_files + c_img_files + d_img_files + e_img_files + f_img_files + g_img_files + h_img_files + i_img_files + j_img_files)

img = load_img(img_path, target_size = (150, 150))
x = img_to_array(img)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)

x /= 255

successive_feature_maps = visualization_model.predict(x)

layer_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]

for layer_name, feature_map in zip(layer_names, successive_feature_maps):
    if len(feature_map.shape) == 4:
# Just do this for the conv/maxpool layers
        n_features = feature_map.shape[-1]
# The feature map has shape(1, size, size, n_features)
        size = feature_map.shape[1]
# Will tile images in this matrix
        display_grid = np.zeros((size, size * n_features))
        for i in range(n_features):
# Postprocess the feature           
            x = feature_map[0, :, :, i]
            x -= x.mean()
            x *= 64
            x += 128
            x = np.clip(x, 0, 255).astype('float32')
# Will tile each filter into this big horizontal grid
            display_grid[:, i * size : (i + 1) * size] = x 
    
# Accuracy results for each training and validation epoch
acc = mymodel.history['acc']
val_acc = mymodel.history['val_acc']

# Loss results for each training and validation epoch
loss = mymodel.history['loss']
val_loss = mymodel.history['val_loss']
```

Comment: Please **remove** any code that comes *after* the error (it is never executed, hence irrelevant), as well as any code that it is irrelevant to it. SO does not work simply by throwing all our code here as-is, please see how to create a [mcve] and why [a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/).

Comment: please see also [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) (tl;dr: **never** - edited out).

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with ML or CNNs - it seems a purely Matplotlib issue.

Answer (score 0):

what i understood from your code , your doing multi class classification because you have used  Dense(10) at the last layer  so
you need  to change class_mode = 'binary' into
`class model ='categorical'` &

also change activation function sigmoid into

```
output = layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax')(x)
```